# can i write on a primary mongoDB database from a secondary clone?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, readonly, replicaset

i tried using the **replicaSet** and i found that is one way directed like for exemple i can add or put in collections from the **PRIMARY** SET and i can read (find) from the **SECONDARY** but it seems that i can't do that and all the stuff linked of replicaSet is done for emergency cases like primary is down so secondary can promote to be primary but the question here is

### can i work on same database (same clusters and collections) from 2 backends!

Comment: Hey youssef, Yes you can write to the same database from 2 backends.

Comment: Welcome.   I think you need to make your question more clear.   It looks like you are saying you can read and write to the primary but can only read from the secondary unless conditions arise to promote the secondary to a primary, and is there a way to read AND WRITE the secondary without "emergency cases."   The answer to *that* question is definitely no.  But an *application* running on a machine hosting the secondary *can* write to the primary.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello every body thanks for answering , 
the problem is i'm working on a mobile project that the web version is already deployed , for some confidential reasons i can't get the full access to the database so i think that maybe replicaset could be a solution like i can get a secondary clone from the data base that would be synchronised with the primary (any changes or updates in the primary automatically are done in the secondary) and when i write in the secondary nothing happen to the primary for the same confidential reasons